# Rails group by id uses a string for hash key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code looks like this:

```
hash = MyModel.count(:group => 'id', :conditions => 'bla = "bla"')
```

The returned `Hash` has keys that are strings. I want them to be ints. I know it would be possible to convert the `Hash` manually using something like a `map` construct.

Edit:

Thanks for the responses. Have realised it was a json conversion process that was turning the ids into Strings and rails does in fact use the Fixnum as one might expect.

Comment: I think all ActiveRecord hashes are stored as strings and are automatically converted to their respective type when instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use your code I get integer keys (rails 3.07), what's the column type of id?

If you want to do it manually:

```
new_hash = hash.inject({}){|h,a| h[a.first.to_i] = a.last; h}
```

Comment: Yea I ended up doing this, just seems a shame that Rails returns integer id as a string. Edit: Rails 2.3.2.

Answer (score 2):

```
hash = MyModel.count(group: 'id', conditions: 'bla = "bla"')
```

should have `Fixnum` keys by default since id is an instance of Fixnum.

What happens is that ActiveRecord **always fetch result as strings** and then Rails takes care of converting them to other datatypes according to the type of the database column (we say that they are typecast).

So it's maybe a Rails bug or the 'id' column is not set as integer(which would be surprising).

If you can't fix it, convert them manually:

```
hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), hash|
  hash[key.to_i] = value
end
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to flesh out my answer a bit :)

Comment: Oh, just the time to grab my Rails 3 Way and to open it page 131 lol

Comment: cool - hadn't seen each_with_object before, comes out a little nicer than inject({})

Comment: @klochner It's just like `inject` but you don't have to re-write `hash` at the end. Also, be cautious because the order of |your_object, new_object| is not the same.

Comment: @Delba - looking at the rails rdoc for each_with_object, i also stumbled across the index_by method that I hadn't seen before - thanks for point me in that direction!

Comment: Another nice one is `group_by` - `index_by` only works as expected if there is only one value per key.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_hash = Hash[hash.map { |k, v| [k.to_i, v] }
```